# Extract horizontal and vertical lines from an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-morphology

I want to extract horizontal and vertical lines in 2 masks for the attached image.

I have tried morphological operations to do this,

```
horizontalStructure = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (horizontal_size, 1))
verticalStructure = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (1, verticalsize))
```

But the problem, It detects the line as a rectangle and then draws it in a form of 2 lines representing the 2 sides of the rectangle.

Any ideas to fix that?

The image:
[image: img]

The horizontal result:

[image: h]

The vertical result:

[image: v]

---

**EDIT:** That's another image I have:

[image: img]

Answer (score 5):

What did you do with your structuring elements? Where's the rest of your code?

I'd suggest to use morphological opening using [`cv2.morphologyEx`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f), like so:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io              # Only needed for web reading images

# Web read image; use cv2.imread(...) for local images
img = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnCvG.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Get rid of JPG artifacts
img = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Create structuring elements
horizontal_size = 11
vertical_size = 11
horizontalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (horizontal_size, 1))
verticalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, vertical_size))

# Morphological opening
mask1 = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontalStructure)
mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, verticalStructure)

# Outputs
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('mask1', mask1)
cv2.imshow('mask2', mask2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the following two masks, which look quite good to me:

[image: Mask 1]

[image: Mask 2]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: @fracv What is a "canny edges effect"? Why don't you provide your actual images in your question right from the beginning? If the unseen images don't (significantly) modify the scope of your question, feel free to add them by editing your question, and I'll have a look. But if they are somehow (totally) different, please ask a separate question, since you would invalidate my current answer, which is unwelcome on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @fracv HansHirse's solution works on the "raw" binary input, not the results of edge detection. You need filled blobs for it. Do not pass your image through an edge detector. It seems that the image you posted is the result of edge detection, but it actually serves no purpose. If that's actually a valid input and not a processing step, you first need to fill those blobs before applying HansHirse's solution. Your contour seems perfectly closed, so you could try flood filling either the background or the actual blobs of interest.